# How download all pictures at the start of mediaManager?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I have been working with DJI Mobile SDK for Android, making my own application by following this tutorial: https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/MediaManagerDemo.html

But i have to download all pictures at once at the start of my gallery, and i coudn't manage how to do it.

Is there any example showing how to do it?

I think it should happen at **[MainActivity.java](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-MediaManagerDemo/blob/a2851debe0187d1083291b2045250f0d3e1ffa81/MediaManagerDemo/app/src/main/java/com/dji/mediaManagerDemo/MainActivity.java)** from the MediaManagerDemo tutorial. Should i create getFiles() and put it alongside getThumbnails and getPreviews (on line 317)?

```
                        scheduler.resume(new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DJIError error) {
                                if (error == null) {
                                    getThumbnails();
                                    getPreviews();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Should i create a Callback for this? What else should i look out?

Thank you all in advance!

**EDIT**: I stopped and thinked calmly about this, and managed to solve this by creating a downloadAllFiles() method after getPreviews(), where it checks if the connection was succeed and calls downloadFileByIndex for each one of the items. I also implemented a way to check if there is already a file with the exact size on internal storage, to avoid unnecessary downloads.

If anyone is interested, [heres my code on Github](https://github.com/Kygra/Android-MediaManagerDemo/commit/2b721a836ac25f821308862290e14445641eb98a)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the section in the tutorial on [Downloading and Editing the Media files](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/MediaManagerDemo.html#downloading-and-editing-the-media-files)?

Comment: Hi Lisa, yeah, i was following this tutorial. After some thinking i managed to solve this by myself, but thanks for the response!